# How to set a breakpoint on a 64 bit process button with x64dbg?

Tags: debugging, memory

I want to find out what certain buttons do on a 64 bit application, x64dbg is the debugger I have available to me, can anyone help me out? I read that ollydbg has an option to break on user input, such as a button, but since the application is question is 64 bit that's not an option. Any help on where to go from here?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use the enhanced **x64dbg** feature for placing **BP** on any window of the debugged app and hence intercept any message being sent to any of them.

After running the **exe**, go to `Handles tab > Right-click >Refresh` -and watch over *Windows* widget and locate the window you want to put the **BP** on. Then Right click->*Message breakpoint*, a window will pop up, now select the desired window message based on what you want to pause your program after. In case of a button, **WM_LBUTTONUP** would do it, in case of an editbox **WM_KEYUP** will also work and so on, you got a ton of messages to choose from. Then you got a couple more checkboxes, select "*...current window*" to pause only when the message is passed to the selected window.
Now, sometimes these windows procs BPs won't work or even pause as expected, in this case, try checking `Use TranslateMessage` option and that would do it.

Comment: where is `windows` widget?

Answer (score 1):

I did it in the following way:

1 go to the window "resources"
2 choose the button corresponding to the application
3 right click and message breakpoint
4 choose "WM_LBUTTONUP"